# Populating contents of Ember.Select view from RecordArray retrieved using Ember-data

Tags: ember.js

I have a select list that is created using this code:

```
      {{view Ember.Select
      contentBinding="App.riskCategories"
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
      selectionBinding="riskCategory"
      class="input-medium"}}
```

*riskCategory* is a property of the *App.Facility* model loaded for the template and the list of *App.RiskCategory* is populated with this code:

```
App.ready = function() {
  App.riskCategories = App.RiskCategory.all()
}
```

This works fine and populates the select list but only with the sub-set of Risk Categories already loaded into the browser. If I call *App.RiskCategory.find()* from the browser console then the rest are loaded and the select list updates however I can't get the code working to do this for me.

So I tried:

```
App.ready = function() {
  App.riskCategories = App.RiskCategory.find()
}
```

or:

```
App.ready = function() {
  App.RiskCategory.find()
  App.riskCategories = App.RiskCategory.all()
}
```

But both of these result in the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Attempted to handle event `loadedData` on <App.Facility:ember417:1> while in state rootState.loaded.updated.uncommitted. Called with undefined
```

I'd appreciate any help or suggestions on a better way to populate the select list. These *App.RiskCategory* objects should be considered an immutable collection of constants stored in the db. Each of the *App.Facility* objects is associated with one of these *App.RiskCategories*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by wrapping the rendering of each *App.Facility* in a {{#if isLoaded}}

So the code looked somthing like:

```
{{#each client.facilities}}
  {{#if isLoaded}}
    {{view Ember.Select
      contentBinding="App.riskCategories"
      optionValuePath="content.id"
      optionLabelPath="content.name"
      selectionBinding="riskCategory"
      class="input-medium"}}
  {{/if}}
{{/each}}
```

It appears that the *App.Facility* object that setting the *App.RiskCategory* hadn't finished loading yet, so the default *App.RiskCategory* was being set and then when the  *dataLoaded* event was fired, the exception was being thrown because the object had already been modified.

Answer (score 3):

Try instead to set the categories in your route and access it in your template through the controller

```
APP.YourRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController:function(controller,model) {
       this._super(controller,model);
       controller.set('riskCategories',App.RiskCategory.find());
    },  

});
```

Assuming your select view is within the same context as the controller, You get access to categories in your template this way:

```
{{view Ember.Select
  contentBinding="controller.riskCategories"
  optionValuePath="content.id"
  optionLabelPath="content.name"
  selectionBinding="riskCategory"
  class="input-medium"}}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I removed the old code hooking into the *App.ready* hook.  and moved it into the *setupController* hook like you suggested. I'm still getting the same issue though.

Comment: Hard to help you without seeing the code. Either provide a jsfiddle or try to debug it using the debugger statement. Make sure you're within the same context.

Comment: ken.. Thanks for the help. I managed to figure it out. The problem was with where I was iterating over the facilities. I needed to wrap the rendering in a {{#if isLoaded}} block...

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and the solution using `#isLoaded` did not work for me. However, what did was to add a `prompt` property to the `Ember.Select`element. I suspect that that has to do with the asynchronicity of rendering the view and loading the data (in my case from `FIXTURES`, but as as far as I know `DS.FixtureAdapter` simulates time-lags in loading data).